# Java JUnit Test Cannot Find Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to run a Test Class that I have created in IntelliJ.  When I run it in IntelliJ the test passes.  However, I want to be able to script it so I am trying to run the test via commandLine.

I am running the following command from this directory:  $PROJECT_HOME/output/test/com/proj1/ome

```
java -cp .:$PROJECT_HOME/tools/junit4.11.jar:$PROJECT_HOME/tools/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ClassATest
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ClassATest (wrong name: com/proj1/ome/ClassATest)
```

I read that this is because you cannot run the project from within the package.  So I went down to the bottom level (recommended by the Stack Overflow post I read) and tried it from there.  So now I was running the following commands from this directory:  $PROJECT_HOME/output/test/com

```
java -cp .:/$PROJECT_HOME/tools/junit4.11.jar:$PROJECT_HOME/tools/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ClassATest
java -cp .:/$PROJECT_HOME/tools/junit4.11.jar:$PROJECT_HOME/tools/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore proj1/ome/ClassATest
```

These gave me the following output

```
JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: ClassATest

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)
```

I then tried going down one more directory and tried it again but got the same results.

Any ideas on where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use the fully qualified class name `com.proj1.ome.ClassATest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be in your $PROJECT_HOME/output/test directory.  Then run:

```
java -cp .:/$PROJECT_HOME/tools/junit4.11.jar:$PROJECT_HOME/tools/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.proj1.ome.ClassATest
```

Comment: should be com.proj1.ome.ClassATest (You forgot the ome)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a ton!
Can't believe I didn't think to use . instead of /.  Such a simple miss.